# pandas dataframe drop problem, want to delete specific rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem to delete specific rows from my dataframe. I want to delete rows that are by matching account number. Here is code:

```
def main():
    
    # Collecting data from .csv
    df1 = pd.read_csv("./2018/Member last activited.csv", 
    sep=";", dtype={"Account Number": str}, encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python')

    accountnum = df1["Account Number"]

    # Collecting data from .csv
    df2 = pd.read_csv("./2019/Member last activited062019.csv", 
    sep=";", dtype={"Account Number": str, "Phone Number": str}, encoding='ISO-8859-1', engine = 'python')

    accountnum2 = df2["Account Number"]

    # comparing account numbers and removing them if matched
 
    tmp2 = {"ID": "0",
        "ACCOUNTNUM": "0"}
    tmplist = []
    for x, y in accountnum.items():
        for z, w in accountnum2.items():
            if y == w:
               tmp2 = {"ID": z, "ACCOUNTNUM": w }
               tmplist.append(tmp2)
    index = 0
    for x in df2["Account Number"]:
        if x == tmplist[index]["ACCOUNTNUM"]:
            df2.drop(index, inplace=True)
        index += 1
```

Comment: accountnum2 = df1["Account Number"], I think you meant to use df2 here.

Please provide more background about the problem and target here.

Comment: yeah you are right. Typo

Comment: now it states that list index is out of range. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to delete the rows from df1 or df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.isin()` method of pandas Series

```py
df2["Account Number"].isin(df1["Account Number"])
```

This will give you Series of boolean values which will be true for all rows where `Account Number` in `df2` is present in `df1` as well. Since, you want to discard those rows, you can use series indexing along with `~` (negation operator) like this:

```py
df3 = df2[~df2["Account Number"].isin(df1["Account Number"])]
```